# How do I use a macrovariable in an if or case statement

Tags: sql, if-statement, while-loop, case

I have a while loop that runs over several years of data. During this time one attribute in some tables I need to join to has changed its name. To get around this I thought I could use a case or if statement. But I'm unable to get the Boolean expression to understand or accept the value in my macrovariable.

Very simplified (with a very short period just for example and all the other code in the while loop is working) my code looks like this:

```
declare @StartYear smallint = 2010
declare @Year smallint = @StartYear
declare @EndYear smallint = 2013
declare @YearVC varchar(4) = ''
declare @CreateTable varchar(MAX) = ''

while @Year <= @EndYear
  begin

   set @YearVC = cast(@Year as varchar)

   set @CreateTable = '
     if ' + @Year + ' < 2011
       select t1.*, t2.a, t2.b, t2.c as e /*Variable t2.e change it´s origin name over time.*/
       into ResultTable_' + @YearVC + '
       from TableOne_' + @YearVC + ' as t1 left join TableTwo_' + @YearVC + ' as t2 on t1.a=t2.a

     if ' + @Year + ' >= 2011
       select t1.*, t2.a, t2.b, t2.d as e /*Variable t2.e change it´s origin name over time.*/
       into ResultTable_' + @YearVC + '
       from TableOne_' + @YearVC + ' as t1 left join TableTwo_' + @YearVC + '  as t2 on t1.a=t2.a
     '

     exec (@CreateTable)

set @Year = @Year + 1

end
```

I've also tried with a case statement (all the variable declarations, the while-loop and the @CreateTAble statement is the same so I just write my select syntax below):

```
select t1.*, t2.b,
  case
    when ' + @Year + ' < 2011 then t2.c
    else t2.d
  end as e
into ResultTable_' + @YearVC + '
from TableOne_' + @YearVC + ' as t1 left join TableTwo_' + @YearVC + ' as t2 on t1.a=t2.a
```

Both these examples give me a Msg 245 error:

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '

with references to my Boolean expressions?

I've made certain in several and different ways that the macrovariable value that I send to that expression is not a varchar. When I try with a varchar variable I get a Msg 207 error instead:

Invalid column name 'd'.

This means that it can't find the attribute name for the attribute which will be valid from 2011 and later.

What am I missing here? How should I define my "if" or "case" statement so that SQL-server will understand that for the years before 2011 it should look for the attribute *c* and for the years from 2011 and further it should look for attribute *d*?

I use MS SQL-server version 14.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. In your secomd query you must surround your select with quotes. In addition, the error that you report is related to year field, which is smallint and you need to convert it to varchar of you want to concatenate it to your string

Comment: For your first attemp, you must perform the if out of set operation, so ‘if @year=2011 set ...’

Comment: Thanks to you all! You saved me a great deal of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to take your IN (really a CASE) statement out of the string:

```
declare @StartYear smallint = 2010
declare @Year smallint = @StartYear
declare @EndYear smallint = 2013
declare @YearVC varchar(4) = ''
declare @CreateTable varchar(MAX) = ''

while @Year <= @EndYear
  begin

   set @YearVC = cast(@Year as varchar)
   set @CreateTable = 
     CASE WHEN @Year < 2011 
        THEN
           'select t1.*, t2.a, t2.b, t2.c as e /*Variable t2.e change it´s origin name over time.*/
           into ResultTable_' + @YearVC + '
           from TableOne_' + @YearVC + ' as t1 left join TableTwo_' + @YearVC + ' as t2 on t1.a=t2.a ;'
        ELSE 
           'select t1.*, t2.a, t2.b, t2.d as e /*Variable t2.e change it´s origin name over time.*/
           into ResultTable_' + @YearVC + '
           from TableOne_' + @YearVC + ' as t1 left join TableTwo_' + @YearVC + '  as t2 on t1.a=t2.a ;'
    END

    EXEC (@CreateTable)

set @Year = @Year + 1

END
```